# Start AsyncTask in Application class; use listener to inform activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I start in `Application` class, in `onCreate`, a background thread (`AsyncTask`) which does some time consuming job (between 15 - 70 seconds).

In an activity I need to make some operations only if that task started in `Application` `onCreate()` method is completed.

My solution for this is:

### `Application` class

- create an interface with a single method
- in `AsyncTask` `onPostExecute` method I update the `listener`
- I have also a `boolean` variable to know from poutside if `asyncTask` is in progress or is terminated

### `MyActivity` class

- I implement the `listener`
- when pressing the button:

  - if `asyncTask` is in progress I set the `listener` and I will be informed in `onCommandEnded` when `AsyncTask` is done and do there the operations
  - if asyncTask job is done I do here the following operations.

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it...

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class MyApplicationClass extends Application {

    protected static MyApplicationClass instance;

    public static MyApplicationClass getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private ApplicationListener listener;
    public void setListener(ApplicationListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
    public static interface ApplicationListener {
        void onCommandEnded();
    }

    private boolean isInProgress;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;

        CommandAsyncTask copyFfmpeg = new CommandAsyncTask();
        copyFfmpeg.execute();
    }

    private class CommandAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Double> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            isInProgress = true;
        }
        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //do some time consuming operations here
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Double aDouble) {
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onCommandEnded();
            }
            isInProgress = false;
            super.onPostExecute(aDouble);
        }
    }

    public boolean isInProgress() {
        return isInProgress;
    }
}




import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyApplicationClass.ApplicationListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (MyApplicationClass.getInstance().isInProgress()) {
                    MyApplicationClass.getInstance().setListener(MyActivity.this);
                } else {
                    //start new asynctask
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCommandEnded() {
        //start here new asynctask
    }
}





<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World, MyActivity"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Start your task in Service class, use BroadcastReceiver to inform Activity.

Comment: Could you please provide me an example ? thansk a lot.

Comment: Use a Service only if you need your background operation to be able to communicate with different activities. What is exactly your problem with your implementation?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is correct the communication between Application class and Activity.

Comment: There are in fact 2 activities which needs to know about that asynctask.

Comment: In order to communicate with a component from an AsyncTask, you need a reference to that component in the AsyncTask itself. This is not possible if your AsyncTask lasts across different Activities (unless you retain a Fragment). At this point you can try the first suggested solution and use the combination Service/BroadcastReceiver.